# Can I get performance testing in node.js like a unit testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, unit-testing, performance-testing

I need performance testing/tuning in nodejs.
In CI/CLI, like a unit test.(target to function call. not networking.)
I use mocha `timeout()` now.

```
var dictionary_handle;
it ("Dictionary.init_dictionary timeout", function(done) {
    dictionary_handle = Dictionary.init_dictionary(dictionary_data);
    done();
}).timeout(1000);

it ("Linad.initialize timeout", function(done) {
    Linad.initialize(function(err){
    done();
    });
}).timeout(6000);
```

But it is not enough.

I need that function.

- able using in CI.
- execute multiple time
- output performance metric information

Comment: Unfortunately, tool/product recommendation questions are off-topic, and often lead to both discussion and spam. Also, there is no "right" answer to such a question. Just opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for a some form of [microbenchmark module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/micro-benchmark). There is a [number](http://node-modules.com/search?u=&q=benchmark) of options and your requirements match them all so I cannot come up with the best candidate, you will need to perform your own investigation.

However given you have `performance-testing` tag added I can give you a generic piece of advice: when it comes to any form of performance testing - you need to make sure that your load test exactly mimics your application under test real life usage.

If your application under test would be a NodeJS-based web application - there are a lot of factors which need to be considered apart from single functions performance so if this is the case I would recommend considering a protocol-level based load testing tool, if you want to stick to JavaScript you can use something like [k6](https://k6.io/) or consider another standalone [free/open-source load testing solution](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) which can simulate real users close enough with minimal efforts from your side.

Answer (score 0):

Dmitri T is correct, you need to be careful with what and how you test. That being said, https://github.com/anywhichway/benchtest require almost no work to instrument existing unit tests, so it may be worth using.